# wal-e : unable to push backups to S3

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3

I followed [this guide](https://coderwall.com/p/cwe2_a) to set up wal-e on our server to push backups to S3. However , when I execute the command:

```
envdir /etc/wal-e.d/env /usr/local/bin/wal-e backup-list
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/wal-e", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2707, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: python-keystoneclient>=0.4.2
```

My python version is 2.7.3

Any idea whats wrong here. I tried searching but no luck so far

Answer (score 1):

The key is in the last line, you need the python-keystoneclient package with version 0.4.2 or greater. If not installed

```
pip install python-keystoneclient
```

If already installed, you can check the version

```
pip show python-keystoneclient
```

And update using

```
pip install python-keystoneclient --upgrade
```